# Find list if not contains with another list of list. Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-requests, data-cleaning

```
import pandas as pd
first_csv = [['a','b'],['a','d'],['a','c']]
second_csv = [['a','b']]
scraped = []
need_to_scrape = []
```

I need to check that **['a','b']** is in **first_csv** then append it into **scraped**
if not then append data into **need_to_scrape**.

```
Output,,
scraped = [['a','b']]
need_to_scrape = [['a','d'],['a','c']]
```

Comment: What have you tried? You should update the post with an attempt at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard `list` comprehension

```
first_csv = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'd'], ['a', 'c']]
second_csv = [['a', 'b']]

scraped = [k for k in first_csv if k in second_csv]
need_to_scrape = [k for k in first_csv if k not in second_csv]

print('scraped', scraped)
print('need_to_scrape', need_to_scrape)

>>> scraped [['a', 'b']]
>>> need_to_scrape [['a', 'd'], ['a', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try `set`

```py
first_csv = [['a','b'],['a','d'],['a','c']]
second_csv = [['a','b']]

first_csv_tuple = set(map(tuple, first_csv))
second_csv_tuple = set(map(tuple, second_csv))

scraped = first_csv_tuple.intersection(second_csv_tuple)
need_to_scrape = first_csv_tuple.difference(second_csv_tuple)

print(scraped) #{('a', 'b')}
print(need_to_scrape) #{('a', 'd'), ('a', 'c')}
```